# Is-braces-constructible type trait

Tags: c++, boost, type-traits, boost-variant

How can I check whether specific type `typename T` is constructible from arguments `typename ...Args` in the manner `T{Args...}`? I aware of `std::is_constructible< T, Args... >` type trait from `<type_traits>`, but it works with parentheses, not curly braces. I do not have too much experience in writing of type traits, so I cannot provide initial example. As simplification we can accept any reasonable assertions, even if this leads to not too significant loss of generality.

Comment: @chris but what about `struct A { std::set< int > a; int b; }; using variant_type = boost::variant< int, double, A >;` variant type? `std::initializer_list{std::decltype< std::set< int > >(), int()}` does not make sense.

Comment: std::is_constructable<T,initializer_list<K>> if all the arguments are the same type....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
template<class T, typename... Args>
decltype(void(T{std::declval<Args>()...}), std::true_type())
test(int);

template<class T, typename... Args>
std::false_type
test(...);

template<class T, typename... Args>
struct is_braces_constructible : decltype(test<T, Args...>(0))
{
};
```

Comment: Can it be expressed in terms of structs/classes, rather then in terms of function return value types?

Comment: You might not need this anymore, but the answer is yes; I took advantage of the priority of the candidate `template<class... S> struct Satisfied<S..., decltype(void(E))>: std::true_type` to the default `template<class... S, class=void> struct Satisfied: std::false_type`. (E should be your expression of {S...} e.g. `S0{std::declval<S>()...}`, you get the idea.) Later you can specialize some `f(...) -> std::enable_if_t<Satisfied<...>::value, ...>` and `f(...) -> std::enable_if_t<!Satisfied<...>::value, ...>` without ambiguity (exactly one candidate after SFINAE.)

Answer (score 2):

My class-SFINAE-based solution:

```
#include <type_traits>


template< typename ...types >
struct identity
{

};

template< typename ...types >
struct void_t
{

    using type = void;

};

template< typename type, typename identity, typename = void >
struct is_embraceable
        : std::false_type
{

};

template< typename type, typename ...arguments >
struct is_embraceable< type, identity< arguments... >, void_t< decltype(type{std::declval< arguments >()...}) > >
        : std::true_type
{

};

template< typename type, typename ...arguments >
constexpr bool is_embraceable_v = is_embraceable< type, identity< arguments... > >::value;
```

Answer (score 2):

in c++20 you can use Requires expressions:

```
template< class T, class ...Args >
inline constexpr bool is_brace_constructible_v = requires {T{std::declval<Args>()...};};
```

Comment: Or with a full concept:

template<typename T, typename ... TArgs>
concept braces_constructible = requires {
    T{std::declval<TArgs>()...};
};

template <braces_constructible T, class... TArgs>
inline constexpr bool is_braces_constructible_v = braces_constructible<T, TArgs...>;

Answer (score 1):

[C++ allows to brace-initialize references](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization), too:

```
struct dummy{};
dummy a;
dummy & b{a};
dummy c{b};

dummy const& d{a};
dummy e{d};
```

But `is_braces_constructible` from [Simple's answer](https://godbolt.org/z/zWOaik) returns `std::false_type` for brace-initialized references with GCC8, but works e.g. with Clang 7. [Orient's ORIGINAL answer](https://godbolt.org/z/Rs2z_R) fails to compile reference brace inits with GCC8, too. [His EDITED answer](https://godbolt.org/z/-AYhnQ) even returns `std::false_type` in much more cases with both GCC8 and Clang 7.

Here is a C++17 answer that (hopefully) works for all cases with GCC8, too:

```
#include <type_traits>

#if __GNUC__

template<
    typename T,
    typename std::enable_if_t<
        std::is_lvalue_reference<T>::value
    >* = nullptr
>
constexpr void gcc_workaround_braces_initialize_refs(T& t);

template<typename T>
constexpr void gcc_workaround_braces_initialize_refs(T const& t);

template<
    typename T,
    typename std::enable_if_t<
        !std::is_lvalue_reference<T>::value
    >* = nullptr
>
constexpr T&& gcc_workaround_braces_initialize_refs(T&& t);

template< typename T, typename Identity, typename = std::void_t<>>
struct is_braces_constructible_impl : std::false_type {};

template< typename T, typename ...Args >
struct is_braces_constructible_impl<
    T,
    std::tuple< Args... >,
    std::void_t< decltype(gcc_workaround_braces_initialize_refs<T>({std::declval< Args >()...}))>
> : std::true_type {};

#else // !__GNUC__

template< typename T, typename Identity, typename = std::void_t<>>
struct is_braces_constructible_impl : std::false_type {};

template< typename T, typename ...Args >
struct is_braces_constructible_impl<
    T,
    std::tuple< Args... >,
    std::void_t< decltype(T{std::declval< Args >()...}) >
> : std::true_type {};

#endif // !__GNUC__

template<class T, typename... Args>
struct is_braces_constructible {
    using type = is_braces_constructible_impl< T, std::tuple< Args... > >;
    static inline constexpr bool value = type::value;
};
```

[Live Code](https://godbolt.org/z/1QDWdD)