# construct boost::variant from parameters pack issue

Tags: c++, boost, type-traits, boost-variant

I tried to write function that allows me to construct a `boost::variant<>` from a parameters pack. In other words, I'm attempting to construct one of the `boost::variant<>::types` type, whose constructor's signature matches the pack, and then convert to `boost::variant<>`. I naively wrote the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh -vex
WARN="-W -Wall -Wextra"
INCLUDE="-isystem /c/libs/boost-trunk"
OPT="-Ofast"
g++ -x c++ - -std=gnu++1y $INCLUDE $WARN $OPT -o a <<__EOF && ./a && echo -e "\e[1;32msucceeded\e[0m" || echo -e "\e[1;31mfailed\e[0m"
#include <boost/assert.hpp>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/placeholders.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/find_if.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/deref.hpp>
#include <boost/type_traits.hpp>

#include <type_traits>

#include <cstdlib>

struct A
{
    A() = default;
};

static_assert( std::is_constructible< A >::value,           " A()"        );
static_assert(!std::is_constructible< A, int >::value,      "!A(int)"     );
static_assert(!std::is_constructible< A, int, int >::value, "!A(int, int)");

struct B
{
    B(int) {}
};

static_assert(!std::is_constructible< B >::value,           "!B()"        );
static_assert( std::is_constructible< B, int >::value,      " B(int)"     );
static_assert(!std::is_constructible< B, int, int >::value, "!B(int, int)");

struct C
{
    C(int, int) {}
};

static_assert(!std::is_constructible< C >::value,           "!C()"        );
static_assert(!std::is_constructible< C, int >::value,      "!C(int)"     );
static_assert( std::is_constructible< C, int, int >::value, " C(int, int)");

using V = boost::variant< A, B, C >;

template< typename V,
          typename ...O >
inline constexpr
V construct(O &&... _o)
{
    using types = typename V::types;
    using predicate = std::is_constructible< boost::mpl::_1, O... >; // I think, that the problem is exactly here.
    using iter = typename boost::mpl::find_if< types, predicate >::type;
    using deduced_type = typename boost::mpl::deref< iter >::type;
#if 1
    return deduced_type(std::forward< O >(_o)...);
#else
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wmissing-field-initializers"
    return deduced_type{std::forward< O >(_o)...}; // second part of the question
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
#endif

}

int main()
{
    V a = construct< V >();
    BOOST_ASSERT(a.type() == typeid(A));
    V b = construct< V >(0);
    BOOST_ASSERT(b.type() == typeid(B));
    V c = construct< V >(0, 0);
    BOOST_ASSERT(c.type() == typeid(C));
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
__EOF
```

It produces a lovely bundle of error messages, the basic meaning of which, as I understand, is that the `std::is_constructible` is not compatible with the `boost::mpl::` library (or more exactly *is not compatible with placeholders from* `boost::mpl::`). In turn, the `boost::` library itself does not contain the (supposedly compatible) `boost::is_constructible` type trait.

Another related problem is to deal with classes like `struct A {}; struct B {int _1;}; struct C {int _1; int _2;};` and to construct them via curly braces, not parenthesis. The main aspect of the last-mentioned problem is absence of type trait, which deduces whether or no some type can be constructed from some pack of arguments. The [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20885988/1430927) does not works with `boost::mpl::`.

Comment: Check `boost::mpl::lambda`

Comment: @K-ballo Well, I'll try.

Comment: [This code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a036d3a044cd03e2) seems to work (emphasis on _seems_). It uses the trait `is_braces_constructible` in the answer you linked. I don't understand why that compiles and your version does not, so I hope you get a good answer and we can both learn. (I've "gratuitously" changed the function `construct` following the advice [here](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2010/09/expressive-c-why-template-errors-suck-and-what-you-can-do-about-it/) to get a less noisy error when you use for example `V d=construct<V>(0,0,0)`, so change it back if you want).

Comment: @cv_and_he Generalization of the original problem is a good thing anyways. I have to take (fortunately) that code as an answer. As for to learn together, much more likely I find in your code something interesting, rather than vice versa. And I already done.

Comment: @cv_and_he predicate should be [lambda expression](http://www.boost.org/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/lambda-expression.html). I.e. `!!predicate::apply< T >::type::value` should have sense.