# is_constructible from curly braces list

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, type-traits, curly-braces

Is there some intention to implement in **STL** variant of `std::is_constructible`, which is suitable for detection whether the specific type is constructible from curly braces, filled with specified parameters pack, or no? I mean something like: `std::is_curly_braces_constructible< T, Args... >::value` is `true` if and only if `T{std::declval< Args >()...}` is well-formed.

I think that such trait would be quite useful.

**EDIT:**

This question is not the duplicate of [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20885541/). Here I ask about the **Standard Template Library**, but not the user code implementations.

Comment: Well, you'd have to ask the standards committee whether they want to implement this...shouldn't be too hard to do by yourself though.

Comment: Go to `<type_traits>` in your favorite standard library and look at how it implements `is_constructible` (it's usually a SFINAE on `decltype(T(declval<Args>()...))`). Change it to `decltype(T{declval<Args>()...})` and you are pretty much done.

Comment: @T.C. [already done](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20885541/).

Comment: You might want to ask this question on the isocpp mailing list: std-discussion@isocpp.org