# MSVC ICE when partially specializing a class template with a decltype of a void-cast expression?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013, internal-compiler-error

**Summary:** is MSVC 2013 right to reject this MCVE following segment of code, even if it does do so in a less than desirable way?

- MSVC 2013, Update 5
- GCC 5.2.0
- Clang 3.7.0

While attempting to create a type trait for checking the validity of brace constructing one type from a single other type

```
B b;
A{b}; // <-- whether this line would be valid code
```

which works in MSVC2013 by adapting code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29251402/4892076) in an attempt to work around MSVC's lack of expression SFINAE support. I have been receiving:

> error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler.

with the location

> compiler file 'f:\dd\vctools\compiler\cxxfe\sl\p1\c\cast.c', line 725

The MCVE below triggers this ICE, even under /Od:

```
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename Type, typename Arg, typename = void>
struct isBraceConsructibleImpl
    : public std::false_type{};

template <typename Type, typename Arg>
struct isBraceConsructibleImpl<Type, Arg, decltype((void)Type{ std::declval<Arg>() }) >
    : public std::true_type{};

int main(int, char**){}
```

As can be seen on [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/676a94cbdf435fb9), gcc and clang are both fine with this (even under -O2). However, while an ICE is most certainly a bug in MSVC, the acceptance of said code by both gcc and clang is no guarantee that it is valid code in the end.

Removing the `Arg` from the template and replacing the `Arg` in the declval with `int` does not reproduce the error:

```
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename Type, typename = void>
struct isBraceConsructibleImpl
    : public std::false_type{};

template <typename Type>
struct isBraceConsructibleImpl<Type, decltype((void)Type{ std::declval<int>() }) >
    : public std::true_type{};

int main(int, char**){}
```

and gcc and clang are [once again fine with it](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c700d7f276a1e5ed).

**Is MSVC is producing an ICE from valid code?**

Comment: MSVC has issues with Expression SFINAE. Code looks fine to me.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2015/04/29/c-11-14-17-features-in-vs-2015-rc.aspx

Comment: An ICE is never ok, it should reject the code if it believes the code is erroneous. Also, the code compiles with VS 2015.

Comment: @Barry Thanks for the sanity check. It seemed highly improbable, but I wasn't sure.

Comment: A language lawyer can't help you here. SFINAE for class template specializations is underspecified. See [CWG 2054](http://wg21.link/cwg2054).

Comment: @T.C. Oh, darn. I suppose it's time to troll through the MSVC 2013 implementation of `is_constructible` then. I suppose it's a case of "Ambiguous, but not a sane response to said ambiguity" then.

Comment: It is not particularly important if other compilers accept some code or not, if you get internal compiler error, it's ALWAYS a compiler bug. We can then discuss whether the code is valid or not when the compiler gives an error message, but if it causes the compiler to completely bail out, it's a bug in the compiler. It should either produce an error or accept the code. If the behavious is undefined, the compiler is then allowed to produce code that crashes, fires missiled, returns 7, or behaves "in some way that you expect" - up to compiler to decide...