# Conditionally enable a constructor whenever a member variable can be constructed by variadic arguments

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, type-traits

I have a class `foo` with template parameter `Tuple` and I want to provide a variadic arguments constructor to initialize a member variable `m_elements` of type `Tuple`, whenever the expression `m_elements{ static_cast<typename Tuple::value_type>(std::forward<Elements>(elements))... }` is defined.

We can do this in the following way:

```
template<class Tuple>
struct foo
{
    using value_type = typename Tuple::value_type;

    template<class... Elements, class U = Tuple,
        class = decltype(U{ static_cast<value_type>(std::declval<Elements>())... })>
    foo(Elements&&... elements)
        : m_elements{ static_cast<value_type>(std::forward<Elements>(elements))... }
    {}

    Tuple m_elements;
};
```

Now, whether this constructor is enabled or not should depend on some other conditions too. So, I would need to write something like

```
template<class... Elements, class U = Tuple,
    class = std::enable_if_t</* some other conditions depending on U */>,
    class = decltype(U{ static_cast<value_type>(std::declval<Elements>())... })>
```

I would like to check my first condition in terms of `std::is_constructible` such that I could move this check into the `enable_if`. Is this possible? I've tried to use `std::is_constructible_v<U, decltype(static_cast<value_type>(std::declval<Elements>()))...>`, but this doesn't seem to be equivalent to the previous check.

For example, `foo<bar<3>>{1, 2, 3};` with

```
template<std::size_t N>
struct bar
{
    using value_type = double;
    double data[N];
};
```

will compile with the previous check, but yields an error with the new one.

Comment: Ironically, `foo` doesn't work when `Tuple` = `std::tuple` because `std::tuple` has no `value_type` attribute, so you aren't *really* working with tuples here (in the sense of heterogeneous compile-time collections).

Comment: @Tim It's not that ironic. My real `foo` is in a math library and a mathematician usually defines a vector to be a n-tuple.

Comment: Ah, *that* kind of tuple. That make much more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Rostislav](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3589890/rostislav) mentioned, if `T` is not a function type, `std::is_constructible_v<T, Args>` is `true` iff the variable definition `T obj(std::declval<Args>()...);` is well-formed. That's not the case in `bar<1> obj(0.);`, cause `bar<1>` has no corresponding constructor.

In contrast, `bar1<1> obj{ 0. };` is well-formed. Using the proposed [Detection Toolkit](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4502.pdf), we could use

```
template<class T, typename... Arguments>
using initializable_t = decltype(T{ std::declval<Arguments>()... });

template<class T, typename... Arguments>
constexpr bool is_initializable_v = is_detected_v<initializable_t, T, Arguments...>;
```

and change the check to

```
template<class... Elements, class U = Tuple,
    class = std::enable_if_t<is_initializable_v<U, decltype(static_cast<value_type>(std::declval<Elements>()))...>>>
```

I think that's more readable than the plain `decltype` approach.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that the `is_constructible` trait behaves differently is that there's indeed no constructor of `bar` taking the three `int` values as an argument. In this particular case, aggregate initialization is used.

But you could put the test into an `enable_if` just by using a simple helper `struct`:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
struct test : std::true_type
{
};

template<class Tuple>
struct foo
{
    using value_type = typename Tuple::value_type;

    template<class... Elements, class U = Tuple,
        class = std::enable_if_t<
            test<decltype(U{ static_cast<value_type>(std::declval<Elements>())... })>::value>
            /* && your other tests */
            >
    foo(Elements&&... elements)
        : m_elements{ static_cast<value_type>(std::forward<Elements>(elements))... }
    {}

    Tuple m_elements;
};


template<std::size_t N>
struct bar
{
    using value_type = double;
    double data[N];
};

int main()
{
    foo<bar<3>>{1, 2, 3};
}
```

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/JDKH73710)

Alternatively, you could push the `decltype` magic to a separate place by creating a type trait using any of the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20885541/is-braces-constructible-type-trait) question.

Comment: your condition of `enable_if` makes little sense. how would you disable a constructor ?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki I don't see what's surprising about disabling a constructor. They're subject to function overloading, too.

Comment: @Quentin then show a constructor that can be picked if this kind of `test` fails, i.e., a constructor that will be used if `U{elements...}` cannot be used

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki oh, you meant in this particular case. Indeed, there's only one constructor here.

Comment: To be precise, I mean, putting `decltype` inside `test`, just to utilize the syntax of `enable_if` makes no sense, what still fails here is the `decltype` itself, not `enable_if`. that said, you wouldn't be able to add another overload of this constructor, that could be enabled if `test` is *false* (whatever it would mean here)

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Yes, but as far as I understood the reasoning for even needing the `enable_if` is to use some conditions in addition to being constructible in a particular way. Unless the conditions need to be or-ed (`||`), the test will work as expected - if there's no way to initialize the member in a desired way, substitution failure will occur due to `decltype`, but if it doesn't then subclassing `true_type` will let other conditions to be checked.

Comment: how is it different from what OP already has, i.e., `class = decltype(...)` ?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Yeah. Well, then the answer doesn't add any additional information apart from why `is_constructible` doesn't work as expected. I'd remove my answer otherwise.